# Defining euclidean function distance using graphics package only

Tags: python, euclidean-distance

```
from graphics import*
def distance(pt1,pt2):
    pt1=Point(x,y)
    pt2=Point(x1,y1)
    sqrt((x-x1) ** 2 + (y-y1) ** 2)
    return distance
distance((100,50),(45,30))
```

## This is the error I'm getting

```
File "/Users/tigersoprano/Documents/test.py", line 7, in <module>
distance((100,50),(45,30))
File "/Users/tigersoprano/Documents/test.py", line 3, in distance
pt1=Point(x,y)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined"
```

## I do not know what i am doing wrong

Comment: Your question is about basic Python, not about graphics or euclidean distance at all.

Comment: It has to do with graphics package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explainatory :

```
pt1=Point(x,y)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined"
```

simply means that you have to tell python what are x, y, x1 and y1 variables.

The function declarationis just `def distance(pt1,pt2):`, so you must express all variables in terms of `pt1` and `pt2` instead of the opposite. For example :

```
def distance(pt1,pt2):
    x = pt1[0]
    y = pt1[1]
    x1 = pt2[0]
    x2 = pt2[1]
    dist = sqrt((x-x1) ** 2 + (y-y1) ** 2)
    return dist
```

Also note that Python is not Fortran : the name of the function should not be used for the name of a variable

If you really want to use the [graphics](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/) package, you should do :

```
def distance(pt1,pt2):
    x = pt1.getX()
    y = pt1.getY()
    x1 = pt2.getX()
    x2 = pt2.getX()
    dist = sqrt((x-x1) ** 2 + (y-y1) ** 2)
    return dist

d = distance(Point(100,50),Point(45,30))
```

Comment: I appreciate it, but is there anyway we could perform this task using the point function from the graphics package specifically?